Problem with Simulating PV Module in MATLAB/Simulink
I'm currently working on simulating the output of a photovoltaic (PV) module based on irradiance and temperature data. Specifically, I have two variables:
irr: A 1x1373798 double representing irradiance data for 16 days.
pvt: A 1x1373798 double representing temperature data for the same 16 days.
However, when attempting to execute the simulation in MATLAB/Simulink, I encountered the following error message:

Error in port widths or dimensions. 'Output Port 1' of 'PV_RealTime/PV Module 3/Diode Rsh/Add1' has 1373797 elements. This port does not accept the dimensions (or orientation) specified by the output signal.
Component:Simulink | Category:Model error
Error in port widths or dimensions. Invalid dimension has been specified for 'Input Port 1' of 'PV_RealTime/PV Module 3/Diode Rsh/Transfer Fcn'.
Component:Simulink | Category:Model error

I believe this error is related to a dimension mismatch, but I'm unsure how to resolve it. How to address this issue?


Welcome Safouane! Have you checked the output of the Current Measurement and the Voltage Measurement? It may not be a scalar.

According to the Matlab Help for the Current Measurement and Voltage Measurement, the output is indeed a scalar, but the default signal format is a complex number, not a real one. There is a parameter for both components to modify this format.
Have a try and let me know.

When I test a single scalar value in the constant blocks, everything works fine. However, for my simulation, I need to test all the values in my vector of irradiance and temperature. Which block should I use to ensure the success of this simulation?

I am no electrician, but I would add a Complex to Magnitude/Angle or a Complex to Real/Imaginary Part between the Current/Voltage Measurements and the following GoTo block. This way, you will be able to use a real-type value for the power computation.
